# Python get anchor text links and href values but ignore image links

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following Python code to scrape anchor text links and corresponding href values from a page path:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.mydomain.co.uk/contact-us"

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)

b  = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(b.text, "lxml")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.text, '-', link.get('href'))
```

It works fine but it also scrapes image links and outputs "-" if its an image. For example:

```
Contact Us - /contact-us
About Us - /about
- /locations
```

I want it to ignore any image href links so the output is:

```
Contact Us - /contact-us
About Us - /about
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if not link.find('img'):
        print(link.text, '-', link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Thanks. It kind of works but still picks some image links up. Is there a way to set it so if the <a> contains src="xxx" then ignore it?

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer. This time it will only print the output if no `img` tag is contained in the `a` tag.